# Travis CI: Split Builds from PHPUnit and Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, travis-ci, laravel-dusk

I would like to set up a testing scenario where I can separate the test-builds for PHPUnit and Laravel Dusk. The reason why is, that this I would like to run different `.env` & `phpunit.xml` files for each test-approach.

1. Set the environment for PHPUnit
2. Test PHPUnit
3. Clean the Travis Build
4. Set the environment for Laravel Dusk
5. Test Laravel Dusk

I've gone through the Travis documentation about jobs and the matrix but I can't find a proper approach which I can follow.

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
sudo: true

dist: trusty

language: php

php:
  - 7.3

addons:
  chrome: stable
  apt:
    sources:
      - mysql-5.7-trusty
    packages:
      - mysql-server
      - mysql-client

services:
  - mysql

install:
  - composer self-update
  - travis_retry composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --no-suggest

before_script:
  - rm composer.lock
  - echo -e "[server]\nmax_allowed_packet=64M" | sudo tee -a /etc/mysql/conf.d/drupal.cnf
  - sudo service mysql restart
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE testing;'
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE business_external;'
  - mysql business_external < /home/travis/build/StanBarrows/business/database/data/business_external
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - cp phpunit.travis.xml phpunit.xml
  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan storage:link
  - php artisan serve &

script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
  - php artisan dusk

notifications:
  email: false
```

Comment: You could define separate environments: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/ Have you used that feature before?